# Rotate and flip Android Fornt Camera2 Image using materix transform

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-camera2, android-camerax

I am using android camera2 front camera with ImageReader function. I am struggling to properly rotate the image output of ImageReader to portate orientation and then draw on the canvas. The front camera makes things even harder because the image is flipped. When I check image rotation it shows as 270. One question is what axis in portrait orientation is the image flipped.

Any code example would be appreciated in order to do this foolproof way for all devices.

```
// rotation of camera.
rotation = 270;
//Matrix
transformationMatrix.setRotate(rotation, imageHeight, 0);
transformationMatrix.postTranslate(-imageHeight, 0);
transformationMatrix.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
transformationMatrix.postScale(-1f, 1f, getWidth() / 2f, getHeight() / 2f);

//draw
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, transformationMatrix, paint);
```